# bind variables not allowed for data definition operations in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a view in Oracle using the below Query, on executing it, throws error message

> bind variables not allowed for data definition operations

When I run the same quer on Query window it executes. On trying to add to view it get this error.

```
SELECT Dept.Name || ' ' || Course.DeptCode AS CourseCode, 'Yes' AS IsActive
FROM Coursetab Course, Depttab dept
WHERE        Course.CODE = Depttab.CODE 
UNION ALL
SELECT Dept.OldName || ' ' || Course.oldDeptCode AS CourseCode, 'No' AS IsNotActive
FROM Coursetab Course, Depttab dept
WHERE        Course.OldCODE = Depttab.oldCODE
```

Comment: Please provide the complete `CREATE VIEW` statement you are attempting to execute.

Comment: I'm new to Oracle, I rightclicked on View to add new view and under Select Query I've given exactly the above query.

Comment: Try to use plain sql to create your DB objects; to create a view, have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504)

Comment: "I rightclicked on View" - in what application? Are you using Toad? SQL Developer? What else? -- As an aside, in a UNION ALL and similar set-theoretic operations, the column names from the first branch will be used for the result. So calling `'No'` as "IsNotActive" will have no effect. Not sure what you meant by that anyway; the column name "IsActive" with possible values "Yes" and "No" is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below how you can create a view:

```
/* Created Tables */
CREATE TABLE Coursetab
(
   DeptCode      NUMBER,
   oldDeptCode   NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE Depttab
(
   name      VARCHAR2 (10),
   OldName   VARCHAR2 (10),
   CODE      NUMBER,
   oldCODE   NUMBER
);

/* Created Successfully view */
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW XYX
AS
   (SELECT Dept.Name || ' ' || Course.DeptCode AS CourseCode,
           'Yes' AS IsActive
      FROM Coursetab Course, Depttab dept
     WHERE Course.DeptCode = Dept.CODE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Dept.OldName || ' ' || Course.oldDeptCode AS CourseCode,
           'No' AS IsNotActive
      FROM Coursetab Course, Depttab dept
     WHERE Course.oldDeptCode = Dept.oldCODE);
```